# Save/Serialize LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Is there anyway to serialize LINQ query in order to persist it and use it later?

Something like this:

```
var serializedQuery = context.Users.Where(row => row.Id == 1).Serialize();
```

It can be serialized to XML, JSON or Binary as long as I can parse it back to a LINQ query.

Comment: Serialize it to what? JSON? XML? Binary?

Comment: You mean the query itself, not the results, right?

Comment: Yes, the query itself. It can be serialized to XML, JSON or Binary as long as I can parse it back to a LINQ query.

Comment: is your question different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404757/save-entity-framework-linq-query-to-database

Comment: [first result on Google...](https://github.com/esskar/Serialize.Linq)

Comment: Seems to be the same. So you need a third party library to do this... I would've thought it was an out of the box feature.

Comment: I would think most people would just implement a compiler and fully compile C# code (like linqpad) over doing something like this.  Seems more functional and there are a number of examples.

Comment: Well, what is the actual problem you're solving that requires serialized linq queries?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# How to serialize system.linq.expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143181/c-sharp-how-to-serialize-system-linq-expressions)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sure, you can use the [first result on google](https://github.com/esskar/Serialize.Linq) which is an open source library that shows you exactly how to do it.  Or you can just use the library as-is.

There's no out of the box feature to do it, as far as I know.  Serializing method signatures and IQueryables is a sticky problem.

Comment: this isn't really an answer, it would be better as a comment. Check the SO Help Center for tips on better answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @jth41 not really, and I did comment above.  No other answers were made so I made this one.